How to clear a specific color channel in a rendertargetview
I have this situation where I would like to use a R16G16 (or 32) float RTV, write on the R channel at start and update only the G channel each frame. Is it possible to clear the RTV in a way the R channel is unaffected without relying on an extra rendering pass let say with a specific shader?
Alternatively I can use a rtv array but I would like to read the RG color with a single texture.sample
The application is for storing depth values, one series being constant (R channel, static objects) the other series being variable (G channel with moving objects).

I think you can accomplish this with an "output write mask".

I don't see clearly what you mean with this output write mask. I post my answer to this but I'm interested to see if something else is working better.

My method for this
First file the RG target with 1s.
Write the depth value you want that should be in the range [0,1] and normally superior to 0. Here I use the red channel for moving objects and green one for static objects. This is why I want to update only the red one. The depth map used here is a distance map for pointlight texturecube.
I first write distance for “objects” moving or not to show the result.
Then a first clear of the red channel. Because the application is for storing normalized distance as [0,1] value the idea is simply to use for the clearing pass a blending stage with a MAX op between SRC and DEST like this:
SrcBlend = D3D11_BLEND_ONE;
DestBlend = D3D11_BLEND_ONE;
BlendOp = D3D11_BLEND_OP_MAX;
For clearing red channel only pass to the pixel shader float2 color = (1,0); The red will be filled with 1s whereas the green will be conserved because the new SRC.g is (normally) not > to current DEST.g.
When using this shadow.rg map in a shader read the rg data and use a min(shadow.r, shadow.g) to have the lowest depth for testing with depth of the scene.
Below a picture of the process.

The benefit is not very high for me as my point lights have a limited radius and are not surrounded by lots of static objects and all my objects are low definitions meshes.

I've tested Adam's suggestion as well.
what works:
blending stage: blendenable false, writemask green. setblendstate sample mask is 0xFFFFFFFF, clearcolor is 1,1,1,1
pixelshader output color = float2(0,1);
This is not intuitive as I'm expecting to clear the red channel and should set write red mask. An explanation is welcome. The result is the same as my first method.

D3D11_RENDER_TARGET_BLEND_DESC contains a RenderTargetWriteMask member, which you can set to some combination of D3D11_COLOR_WRITE_ENABLE flags to control which colour channel(s) get written to. For example, setting it to D3D11_COLOR_WRITE_ENABLE_RED | D3D11_COLOR_WRITE_ENABLE_ALPHA will limit writes to the red and alpha channels only.
Once you've applied an appropriate blend state, you can then render a quad to fill the selected channels of the render target with the values that you require.
Note that writing to a subset of the channels in a texture is usually more expensive than writing to all of the channels, because the GPU needs to do a per pixel read-modify-write operation to preserve the contents of the channels that you're not writing to.

My method is equivalent to this but the shader I use allows me to write all channels and more importantly I can orient writing the depth depending on the static/mobile status of the object.
